# Function to exclude category posts for not logged in users

Tags: wordpress, function, authentication, categories

Is it possible to add a *function* to the wordpress theme function.php file to exclude (read: completely hide) posts from a certain category if user is not logged in?

I know there are plugins to hide categories in the admin section. But this is about the front-end. And I also found plugins that hides the post content, but still shows the title and some kind of login message. But I want to completely *hide* it as if the post does not exists. I understand it would be possible to add the below code in the loop in different files:

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
query_posts();
}
else{
query_posts( cat= -1 );
}
?>
```

But is it possible to just add one function to make that happen? Or is this not how it works? Please enlighten me ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [pre_get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action. Something like the following should work:

```
function exclude_posts_from_category($query) {
    if (is_user_logged_in() && $query->is_main_query()) {
        $query->set('post__not_in', array(1));
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_posts_from_category');
```

Comment: Thank you Mevius. Hope I understand the code. The pre_get_post is an exsiting wp function? And this function is added to wherever that wp function is in action and commands to include this new function?

Comment: The above code would be added to **functions.php**. `pre_get_posts` is a default [WordPress Action hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference). If I understand you correctly, it seems that you understand the general concept :-)

Comment: aha, thx1 Make me feel good ;-)

I tried your code, and the code below, but both did not show any difference (page was not blanc, but post of both category 1 and 9 were still vissible for not logged in users:

`function exclude_posts_from_category( $query ) {
        if ( !is_user_logged_in() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
       $query = new WP_Query( 'cat=-9,-1' );`
        }
    }
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_posts_from_category' );`

Comment: ?how can I put the code here to make it display as in question and answer section?

Comment: You should be using `$query->set('post__not_in', array(YOUR_IDs));`

Comment: By Your ID's you mean post ID? Or Category ID? For I used your code with Category ID, but posts from that category still showed. I try to exclude all posts from a certain category.